# Tensors and coordinate transformations

Tags: coordinate-systems, tensors

I was wondering if there's a difference between the terms "coordinate transformation" and "change of coordinates" from the point of view of tensors.
Here's what I mean. If we have a cartesian coordinate system $X$ and we rotate it by some angle $\theta$, we have a new coordinate system $X'$ where we can get the components $v'^i$ of any vector $\vec V$ in terms of its components $v^i$ in $X$. Since $V$ is a tensor, its components in $X'$ & $X$ are related by $$V'^i = \frac{\partial x'^i}{\partial x^j}V^j$$
Now consider a vector $A$ in cartesian coordinates and the same vectors in polar coordinates. Are the components of $A$ in polar coordinates related to the components in Cartesian coordinates via the same equation given above?
When write down the equations, it gives me that the components are functions of the position. For example, $$A^r = cos(\theta)A^x + sin(\theta)A^y$$
And I don't really understand what that means. Why are the components of a constant vector, that's one and the same in any coordinate representation, depend on a coordinate?

I worded it as best as I could, yet it still sounds confusing.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of confusion seems to come from mixing up vectors (and tensors) with *vector (or tensor)* ***fields***. In a lot of literature the word *field* is omitted for brevity.

In two dimensions the coordinate transformation between cartesian and polar coordinates is
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)\mapsto\left(\begin{matrix}r\\\varphi\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\\\arctan(\frac{y}{x})\end{matrix}\right)\,.
$$
The back transformation is
$$
\left(\begin{matrix}r\\\varphi\end{matrix}\right)\mapsto\left(\begin{matrix}x\\y\end{matrix}\right)=\left(\begin{matrix}r\cos\varphi\\r\sin\varphi\end{matrix}\right)\,.
$$
These maps are one to one when restricted to $M=\mathbb R^2\setminus\{0\}\,.$

So far the above maps only express *points* on the manifold in different languages. Recall that a *tensor field* on the manifold is a map from $M$ into the tensor product of a selection of (co-)tangential spaces. For example, a contravariant vector field is
$$\tag{1}
V=v^x\partial_x+v^y\partial_y
$$
where $v^x,v^y$ are functions on $M$ and $\partial_x,\partial_y$ are a basis of $T_pM\simeq\mathbb R^2\,.$ The $x,y$-notation indicates that $V$ is expressed in cartesian coordinates. To express $V$ in polar coordinates we use the chain rule:
\begin{align}
\partial_x&=\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\partial_r+\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial x}\partial_\varphi=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\partial_r-\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}\partial_\varphi=\cos\varphi\,\partial_r-\frac{\sin\varphi}{r}\,\partial_\varphi\,,\\
\partial_y&=\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\partial_r+\frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial y}\partial_\varphi=\frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\partial_r+\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\partial_\varphi=\sin\varphi\,\partial_r+\frac{\cos\varphi}{r}\,\partial_\varphi\,.
\end{align}
Plugging this into (1) gives us the vector field in polar coordinates:
$$\tag{2}
V=\underbrace{(v^x\cos\varphi\,+v^y\sin\varphi)}_{\displaystyle =:v^r}\,\partial_r+\underbrace{\frac{-v^x\sin\varphi+v^y\cos\varphi}{r}}_{\displaystyle=:v^\varphi}\,\partial_\varphi\,.
$$
To shed some light on the concept of $\partial_x,\partial_y$ being vector fields recall that, for a real valued function $f$ on $M$ and a curve $\gamma$ passing through $p=\gamma(0)\,,$ the chain rule gives for the derivative of $f$ along the tangent of the curve
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_{t=0}f(\gamma(t))&=\partial_xf(\gamma(0))\,\gamma_1'(0)+\partial_yf(\gamma(0))\,\gamma_2'(0)\\
&=\partial_xf(p)\,\gamma_1'(0)+\partial_yf(p)\,\gamma_2'(0)\\
%&=\langle\nabla f(p),\gamma'(0)\rangle\,.
\end{align}
If we remove the test function $f$ from this relationship we get the RHS as
$$
\gamma_1'(0)\,\partial_x|_p+\gamma_2'(0)\,\partial_y|_p\,.
$$
This shows that $\gamma_1'(0),\gamma_2'(0)$ are the components of a general tangential vector in $T_pM$, and $\partial_x|_p,\partial_y|_p$ are the basis vectors.

See also [Tangent Space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_space#Formal_definitions).

Comment: I know very little differential geometry so your answer isn't completely understandable for me. Is there another way to explain this that's not that much involved?

Comment: @user626542 : I have tried to use as little differential geometry as possible (mostly because I know very little of it either). What exactly isn't completly understandable? The concept of $\partial_x,\partial_y$ being vectors ?

Comment: Put it like this. Is there a way to answer my question without using differential geometry at all? I know this is probably the right setting to discuss tensors.  But it's very unfamiliar for me. I know the definitions of manifolds, curves on manifolds, functions from a manifold to another, etc. But it's not something easily accessible to me.

Comment: I am fully convinced that there isn't a lot of DG needed to understand my answer above. Perhaps nothing extra after I wrote the edit?  Your question was "Why are the components of a constant vector, that's one and the same in any coordinate representation, depend on a coordinate?" . As an answer I tried to show that the vector field $V$ has components that do depend on the coordinates, regardless if cartesian or polar. It could help if you ask further specific questions as basic as they might be.