# Why are the eigenvalues of this problem different in polar and Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

I'll admit I'm not really an expert on coordinate transformations, so my error/misunderstanding may be a simple fix; in fact, that would be ideal.

I'm trying to determine the eigenvalues of the Lamb-Oseen vortex velocity gradient field. The Lamb-Oseen velocity field in polar coordinates is given as
$$
\vec{u}(r,t) = \begin{bmatrix} u_r \\ u_\theta \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ \frac{\Gamma}{2\pi r} (1 - e^{-r^2/(4 \nu t)}) \end{bmatrix}
$$
When I compute the gradient in polar coordinates, I get the following form:
$$
\nabla \vec{u} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial r} \\ \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \theta} & \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial \theta} \end{bmatrix}
$$
(Maybe it should be transposed, but that doesn't end up mattering here.) Clearly, $\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial r}$ is the only non-zero term, so the eigenvalues will both be zero as well.

The physical problem with this is that the eigenvalues should have at least some non-zero imaginary part because the swirl criterion for vortex identification should identify pretty much the entire field as a vortex, and it is defined as the magnitude of the imaginary part of the velocity gradient eigenvalues. Indeed, when I compute the eigenvalues in Cartesian coordinates using the following form, I *do* get non-zero imaginary eigenvalues.
$$
\vec{u}(x,y,t) = \begin{bmatrix} u \\ v \end{bmatrix} = \frac{\Gamma}{2\pi (x^2 + y^2)}  \bigg(1 - e^{-(x^2 + y^2)/(4 \nu t)}\bigg)\begin{bmatrix} -y \\ x\end{bmatrix}
$$
***Edit:*** I originally (mistakenly) put $\frac{\Gamma}{2\pi \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$, but that was simply an error writing it.
I'm assuming one of two problems:

1. I'm just not doing the transformation/polar gradient correctly, so the terms should look different.
2. The eigenvalues are unique to the coordinate system. I could see how the values themselves might change between coordinate systems, but all zeros to imaginary non-zero numbers seems wrong.

I would appreciate any explanation of what I might be misunderstanding or someone pointing out a mistake I made in my process.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand why $u_r$ is zero, since that would mean that the field would be zero everywhere. But the $u(x,y,t)$ vectors are not zero everywhere. OTOH, possibly I am mistaken, I admit that I have no familiarity with the Lamb-Oseen vortex velocity gradient field.

Comment: The gradient of a vector field in polar coordinates isn't what's shown. [See these notes](https://www.continuummechanics.org/cylindricalcoords.html) for more info on the more general cylindrical coordinates case.

Comment: OK, from the answer I understand that what is meant is that $u_r$ is the derivative of the $r$ component of the vector, not the $r$ component itself.

Comment: @RonKaminsky, no $u_r$ is the radial component of velocity. It is a vortex with Gaussian vorticity and no radial component.

Comment: @RyanKelly Thanks, now I remember why I hated curvilinear coordinates so much. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @A rural reader for pointing out the issue. For completeness, I'll spell out the answer here:

The velocity gradient has a couple more terms I've neglected by accident, and it *should* look like this:

$$
\nabla \vec{u} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial u_r}{\partial r} & \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial u_r}{\partial \theta} - \frac{u_\theta}{r} \\ 
\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial r} & \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial \theta} + \frac{u_r}{r} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Now with $u_\theta$ and $\frac{\partial u_\theta}{\partial r}$ on the off-diagonal elements the eigenvalues are non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

- Coordinate transformations are always just based on the chain rule.
- When we transform vector fields we cannot transform their components as if they were scalars. That was the (forgivable) sin you committed :). It happened to me as well.

In polar coordinates your vector field is of the form
$$
\textstyle\boldsymbol{u}=u_r\,\partial_r+u_\theta\,\frac{1}{r}\partial_\theta
$$
where
\begin{align}
u_r&=0\,,&u_\theta=\frac{\Gamma}{2\pi r} (1 - e^{-r^2/(4 \nu t)}) \,.
\end{align}

According to [first principles (chain rule)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4310827/tensors-and-coordinate-transformations/4311382#4311382),
\begin{align}
u_x&=u_r\cos\theta-u_\theta\sin\theta=\frac{\Gamma}{2\pi\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} (1 - e^{-(x^2+y^2)/(4 \nu t)})\,\color{red}{\frac{-y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}\,,\\
u_y&=u_r\sin\theta+u_\theta\cos\theta=\frac{\Gamma}{2\pi\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} (1 - e^{-(x^2+y^2)/(4 \nu t)})\,\color{red}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}}\,.
\end{align}
These expressions can be simplified by which your $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ becomes $x^2+y^2\,.$ Now I am curious to see that Jacobian $\nabla\boldsymbol{u}$ again.

Comment: Dang, in reality I just wrote the equation down wrong. That square root on the Cartesian form was not supposed to be there, I was just incorrectly remembering it (incidentally, I should remember to double-check that when I'm doing calculations). Good catch, but it still doesn't quite get to the answer I'm looking for which is why the polar form is zero, but I think someone's comment answered that by pointing out my gradient is a little off.