# Lie Bracket in curvilinear coordinates

Tags: transport-equation, coordinates

When one works with Euler's equation in its vorticity formulation, one needs to work with the transport equation

$$(B\cdot \nabla)j=(j\cdot \nabla)B.$$

If one just uses cartesian coordinates this is (Einstein's notation assumed)

$$\left(B_\alpha\frac{\partial j_\beta}{\partial x_\alpha}-j_\alpha\frac{\partial B_\beta}{\partial x_\alpha}\right)e_{\beta}=0.$$

In a more geometrical formulation, this means that the Lie bracket of the fields, $[B,j]=0$ vanishes. Working with this I came across this apparent contradiction

On the one hand, the Lie bracket is a geometrical quantity, whose expression in coordinates does not depend on the choice of parametrization I take. So if I wanted to use cilindrical coordinates, the equation above should be identical but substituting $\alpha,\beta\in \{1,2,3\}$ for  $\alpha,\beta\in \{\rho,\phi,z\}$.

On the other hand, if one checks the formula for the quantities $(A\cdot \nabla)B$ in books, one sees that the resulting $(A\cdot\nabla)B-(B\cdot\nabla)A$ cannot be written like that in cilindrical or spherical coordinates. In particular, there are some annoying factors $\frac{1}{\rho}$ messing up the neat expression I would like to obtain (for instance, in [Wikipedia's page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates))

I am sure that there is some subtlety (maybe not too subtle) I am not seeing, but I don't know if it is because my premise is wrong (the equation is not $[j,B]=0$), or what.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When you understand 2D polar coordinates you understand cylindrical coordinates. Formulas (2) and (3) in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4772861/949989) show how components of vectors and the coordinate basis vector fields transform. In other words, one and the same vector field $\boldsymbol{V}$ can be written as
$$\tag{A}
\boldsymbol{V}=V^x\partial_x+V^y\partial_y=V^r\partial_r+V^\phi\partial_\phi
$$
where (in slightly different notation than in the linked answer)
\begin{align}
\partial_r&=(\cos\phi)\,\partial_x+(\sin\varphi)\,\partial_y\,,\\[2mm]
\partial_\varphi&=-r(\sin\phi)\,\partial_x+r(\cos\varphi)\,\partial_y\,,\\[2mm]
V^r&=(\cos\varphi)V^x+(\sin\varphi)V^x\,,\\[2mm]
V^\phi&=-\tfrac1r(\sin\phi)V^x+\tfrac1r(\cos\phi)V^x\,.
\end{align}

- I invite you to derive these equations from the [chain rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4729236/deriving-the-gradient-operator-in-spherical-coordinates/4729311#4729311).
- You already see the "annoying factors" $r$ and $\frac1r$ lurking in these
  equations but note that the following will become particularly simple when they stay on the right hand sides rather than being incorporated into, say, $\frac1r\partial_\phi\,.$ This is just a normalization of the basis
  vector field but it has the drawback that the new basis $\{\partial_r,\frac1r\partial_\phi\}$ is not longer [holonomic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4540699/949989). This non holonomic form is used in many $\nabla$ formulas displayed in Wikipedia.
- Now I show what is coordinate invariant when using the holonomic bases (aka "coordinate bases") $\{\partial_x,\partial_y\}$ and $\{\partial_r,\partial_\phi\}\,:$
- With another vector field
  $$\tag{B}
  \boldsymbol{U}=U^x\partial_x+U^y\partial_y=U^r\partial_r+U^\phi\partial_\phi
  $$
  we can look at the The Lie bracket
  \begin{align}
  [\boldsymbol{U},\boldsymbol{V}]&=\boldsymbol{U}\boldsymbol{V}-\boldsymbol{V}\boldsymbol{U}\,
  \end{align}
  and show that it is a tensor. First, it is obviously coordinate invariant
  since the two vector fields are.
  It remains to show that this commutator equals the difference
  of two directional derivatives by which it is a
  coordinate invariant first order differential operator, hence, a tensor.
  To do this let's write (A) and (B) in index notation
  $$
  \boldsymbol{V}=V^a\partial_a=V^\mu\partial_\mu
  $$
  where Latin indices denote the Cartesian coordinates and Greek
  indices the polar coordinates. Same for $\boldsymbol{U}\,.$
  Then, by the product rule
  \begin{align}
  \boldsymbol{U}\boldsymbol{V}&=
  (U^a\partial_a)(V^b\partial_b)=(U^a\partial_aV^b)\,\partial_b+U^aV^b\partial_a\partial_b\,.
  \end{align}
  The first term is the directional derivative $\partial_{\boldsymbol{U}}\boldsymbol{V}$ and the
  second term a second order derivative that is symmetric in $a$ and $b$
  (hence in $\boldsymbol{U}$ and $\boldsymbol{V}\,$). Since
  in the difference $\partial_{\boldsymbol{U}}\boldsymbol{V}-
  \partial_{\boldsymbol{V}}\boldsymbol{U}$
  the second order derivatives cancel we obtain
  $$
  [\boldsymbol{U},\boldsymbol{V}]=\partial_{\boldsymbol{U}}\boldsymbol{V}-
  \partial_{\boldsymbol{V}}\boldsymbol{U}\,.
  $$
- Final remark: these facts hold in any coordinate system (not only in Cartesian and polar coordinates) as long as we use coordinate bases $\partial_a$ and $\partial_\mu\,.$