# Applying a Vector Field Defined in Cylindrical Coordinates $(r, \phi, z)$ to Points in Cartesian Coordinates $(x, y, z)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, transformation, vector-fields, python

I have written a Python script that defines a meshgrid. The meshgrid represents a 3D grid in Cartesian (x, y, z) coordinates, and for each point, I want to apply a function. After applying the function to all points, I should obtain a vector field.

Firstly, I convert each given point to cylindrical coordinates using the following equations:
$$r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
$$\phi = \arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
Since my `func` takes cylindrical coordinates and returns cylindrical coordinates:
`r, \phi, z = func(r, \phi, z)`

I need to convert the coordinates back to Cartesian (x, y, z):

$$x = r\cos(\phi)$$
$$y = r\sin(\phi)$$

When I plot the points after running the script, the results are not as expected.
I defined `func` to be the magnetic field:

$$func(r, \phi,z) = \hat{\phi}\left(\begin{cases} \frac{R^2}{3\cdot r}& R\leq r\\ \frac{r^2}{3\cdot R} &r < R\end{cases}\right)$$

and is seems the convertion of vector back to Cartesian, ignores the magnitude of the rotation effect the magnetic field does. the result plot looks like that:
[image]

I achieve the expected result only after taking the return value of  `func` as the new radius $(r)$ and defind the vectors with the following convertion: $(-r\cdot sin(t), r\cdot cos(t), 0)$:
[image]

Comment: It sounds like the function returns not a point in $\mathbb R^3$ but components of a vector field. I once ran into similar problems until I learned once and for all that components of vector fields transform [differently](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4762000/949989) from the points in $\mathbb R^3\,.$

Comment: What is $\hat \phi ?$

Comment: if your function returns polar cooardinates for the direction of the vector then of course you need to convert them back before plotting. btw: i noticed you used arctan. you might want to use arctan2 which takes 2 arguments and works in all 4 quadrants and does not have an issue at 0

Comment: @KurtG, after following the link you provided, if I take the return value from the  ```func```  function as $f_{\phi}$, then I need to solve this system of equations:
$$\begin{cases}
V_{x}\cdot\cos(t)+V_{y}\cdot\sin(t)=0\\
-V_{x}\cdot\sin(t)+V_{y}\cdot\cos(t)=f_{\phi}\\
V_{z}=0\end{cases}$$
I then plot the vector $\vec{V}=V_{x}\hat{x} + V_{y}\hat{y} +V_{z}\hat{z}$
which works perfectly!
However, in the link you provided, it seems the second equation should be:
$$\frac{-V_{x}\cdot\sin(t)+V_{y}\cdot\cos(t)}{r}=f_{\phi}$$
In that case, I get a different plot. What is the reason for that?

Comment: The reason for that division by $r$ is normalization to unit length of the angular basis vector $\hat{\phi}\,.$  By convention, that $\hat{\phi}$ has unit length and is $\frac1r\partial_\phi\,.$ This [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4540699/949989) gets to the bottom of it.